# The specified database connection is not defined: legacy

Tags: migrations

I used Drush command to migrate

```
drush migrate-upgrade --legacy-db-url=mysql://root:@127.0.0.1/tsa_v8 --legacy-root=http://127.0.0.1/new_projects/tsa --configure-only
```

But it return error: **The specified database connection is not defined: legacy**. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `--legacy-db-key` option which allows you to use a $databases array, with matching key, defined in `settings.php`.

So, your drush command can be sth like:

```
drush migrate-upgrade --legacy-db-key=tsa7 --legacy-root=http://tsa7.com --configure-only
```

And in your `settings.php` or `settings.local.php`:

```
$databases['tsa7']['default'] = array(
  'database' => 'tsa7',
  'username' => 'tsa7_user',
  'password' => 'tsa7_pass',
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'port' => '',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
);
```